# Increment COOKIE on window open

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

All I want to do is increment a COOKIE for each opened tab. Management of the COOKIE variable will be in PHP, I've sorted that out, but I don`t really know how to test if a new window has been opened (Javascript or Jquery). Any heads up? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot tell if a new window/tab has been opened from the server side. you can guess it however, by constantly sending a signal from an already open window to the webserver (e.g., ping the server from the page via ajax every X seconds).

edit:

if you only want to detect that a new tab has been on the client side only, there are several things you can do:

- user clicks on a link/button, and you open a new window/tab because of that click (e.g., via a window.open() call), then you simply increment the cookie as you would normally increment cookies in javascript, and do it at the same place as your window.open() call.
- if the user typing a url in a new tab is also considered opening a new window (e.g., your program isn't responsible for initiating the window...say, it was a middle/shift click on an anchor), then it gets more difficult to detect using javascript alone. One way is to add a field into [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage), and increment it when the page loads, and decrement it when the page is closed (listen for the unload event, like `window.onbeforeunload`). Then, to check how many windows is currently open, you can read that field. Unfortunately, this won't work on lesser browsers like IE(6|7|8).

Comment: I don`t want to do it server side. Javascript or Jquery, as the tags imply, thank you!